# How to vectorize such an algorithm in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, vectorization

I have four (nx1) dimensional arrays named a, b, c, and F. I want to run this algorithm without any loops.

```
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] < b[i]:
        F[i] = 0
    elif a[i] > c[i]:
        F[i] = 1
    elif b[i] <= a[i] <= c[i]:
        F[i] = 2
```

I want to write this code in a more vectorized way to make it more efficient as my dataset is quite large.

Comment: In numpy terms, 'vectorize' means performing the iteration in compiled code.  Usually that means using compiled numpy methods. But compiling your own code with numba can do just as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've tried your suggestion before, as @AboAmmar suggested.

Comment: You could have avoided a lot of that discussion in @NiziL answer by providing a [mcve] - example arrays that you expect to work.

Comment: Yeah you're right 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about performance, why not try `numba`? It might get `10X` faster than logical operations while saving memory at the same time. As a bonus, the loop code you wrote will be kept intact, only through an `@njit` decorator in front of the function.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def loop(F, a, b, c):
  for i in range(F.shape[0]):
    if a[i] < b[i]:
      F[i] = 0
    elif a[i] < c[i]:
      F[i] = 1
    elif b[i] <= a[i] <= c[i]:
      F[i] = 2
```

Compare with vectorized solution by @NiziL using sizes of 100 and 1000 vectors,

```
timeit(lambda: loop(F, a, b, c))
timeit(lambda: idx(F, a, b, c))
```

Gives:

```
# 1.0355658 (Size: 100, @njit loop)
# 4.6863165 (Size: 100, idx)

# 1.9563843 (Size: 1000, @njit loop)
# 16.658198 (Size: 1000, idx)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works correctly.  But does it the best way to vectorize this algorithm?

Comment: Yes, `numba` does a really a good job optimizing any python code having loops unless there is an optimized low level version, from `numpy` for example, that does the whole algorithm in one pass. Even if some steps of the algorithm are available as `numpy` functions, the `numba` version will still be faster because it optimizes the whole function without having to store intermediate results.

Comment: thank you very much for the useful hints. I've run a code with your instructions, and it was amazingly fast by use of numba.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like you could use boolean indexing for this task.

```py
F[np.logical_and(b <= a, a <= c)] = 2
F[a > c] = 1
F[a < b] = 0
```

Beware, the affectation order is important here to get the desired outcomes.

Some `timeit` benchmark:

```py
def loop(F, a, b, c):
  for i in range(F.shape[0]):
    if a[i] < b[i]:
      F[i] = 0
    elif a[i] > c[i]:
      F[i] = 1
    elif b[i] <= a[i] <= c[i]:
      F[i] = 2

def idx(F, a, b, c):
  F[np.logical_and(b <= a, a <= c)] = 2
  F[a > c] = 1
  F[a < b] = 0
```

with (10x1) array:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: loop(F, a, b, c))
11.585818066001593
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: idx(F, a, b, c))
3.337863392000145
```

with (1000x1) array:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: loop(F, a, b, c))
1457.268110728999
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: idx(F, a, b, c))
10.00236530300026
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said, the affectation order is important here to get the desired outcomes. I checked your suggestion code with various orders, and the results were different. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Actually, I want the code to do the calculations (based on the if-else conditions) for all members of the array F, simultaneously.

Comment: Well, the order in your `if-else` block is actually important too, isn't it ? `a[i] < b[i]` and `a[i] > c[i]` can both be true, so the first checked condition will have the priority. So I've basically reversed your condition order to ensure `F[...] = 0` will erase other affectations, and so have the "priority"... Not sure if I'm understandable here...

Comment: The order in my if-else block doesn't make any difference in the final results. But your suggestion code results are affected by the orders.

Comment: @MiladAnboohiso Really ? if `a[i] < b[i]` and `a[i] > c[i] ` are both true, the order is important. I don't get how the result can stay the same without any constraint on b and c.... maybe b is always smaller than c ? Btw, I don't think you can "overcome" this problem with my approach, just have to find the right order.

Comment: Yes, you are right. b is always smaller than c. They work like thresholds.

Comment: @MiladAnboohi I've just though about this: you could check if there is collision by calling `np.logical_and(a>c, a<b).any()` (you can add all your condition here). If the result is true then the order matter (there is at least one collision), else the order does not. if b really is always smaller than c, I actually don't get why there is collision... you can also check this assumption with `(b<c).all()`